# multi-series bar graph displayed as stack bar instead of displaying the series side by side

Tags: jquery, graph, charts, flot

i'm using a multi-series bar graph on my project, all seems well except the display style of the graph, instead of displaying each series side by side it displays like a stacked bar graph's behavior..i used this method..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

 var ms_data = [{"label":"FOO","data":[[0,80],[1,70],[2,100],[3,60],[4,102]]},
             {"label":"BAR","data":[[0,10],[1,20],[2,30],[3,40],[4,80]]},
             {"label":"CAR","data":[[0,5],[1,10],[2,15],[3,20],[4,25]]}]
var ms_ticks = [[0,"sample5"],[1,"sample4"],[2,"sample3"],[3,"sample2"],[4,"sample1"]];

function plotWithOptions() {
  $.plot($("#placeholder"), ms_data, {
    bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.6, series_spread: true, align: "center" },
    xaxis: { ticks: ms_ticks, autoscaleMargin: .10 },
    grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true }
  });
}

function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y + 5,
        left: x + 5,
        border: '1px solid #fdd',
        padding: '2px',
        'background-color': '#fee',
        opacity: 0.80
    }).appendTo("body").show();
}

plotWithOptions();

$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
  $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
  $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));
    if (item) {
        if (previousPoint != item.datapoint) {
            previousPoint = item.datapoint;

            $("#tooltip").remove();
            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                        item.series.label + " Group id: " + Math.floor(x) + ", y = " +    y + ", seriesIndex: " + item.seriesIndex);
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#tooltip").remove();
        previousPoint = null;            
    }
});

$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        $("#clickdata").text("You clicked bar " + item.dataIndex + " in " +  item.series.label + ".");
    }
  });

  });
  </script>
```

Comment: What flot plugin(s) do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you use is from a very old `flot` version (version 0.5 from 2009). The current version (0.8.x) does not support the `series_spread` option.

You can use the [SideBySideImproved](https://github.com/pkoltermann/SideBySideImproved) plugin to get that function with the current `flot` version.

I build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7mtZ/1/) based on you example and changed the following to get your desired function.

For each dataseries:

```
bars: {
    order: 1   // 1, 2, 3 for the three data series
},
```

And under the options:

```
bars: {
    show: true,
    barWidth: 0.2,   // the sum must be less than 1.0
    // series_spread: true,
    align: "center"
},
```